# Signing a String using an identity and trust from a PKCS #12 Bundle

Tags: swift, cryptography

One of the requirements of a third-party SDK I am integrating with is to sign an identifier string with the identity from a p12 certificate.  This code loads a p12 certificate from the application's bundle, opens the cert with the specified key, retrieves the key, signs an input string (the `requestorID`) with the information in the certificate, and encodes the signed data as a base64 encoded String.

```
import Security

// ...

func signRequestorId(requestorID: String) -> String? {

    guard let certificatePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Certificate", ofType: "p12"), certificateData = NSData(contentsOfFile: certificatePath) else {
        return nil
    }

    let certificateKey = "certificateKey"

    var signedBytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>
    var privateKey: SecKeyRef?
    var myReturnedCertificate: SecCertificateRef?
    var signedRequestorId: String?
    var status: OSStatus

    let options = [kSecImportExportPassphrase as String : certificateKey]

    var items: CFArrayRef?
    var securityStatus = SecPKCS12Import(certificateData, options, &items)

    if securityStatus == errSecSuccess {

        // Unwrap optional CFArrayRef of items from the certificate
        if let items = items {
            // Cast CFArrayRef to Swift Array
            let itemsArray = items as [AnyObject]
            // Cast CFDictionaryRef as Swift Dictionary
            if let myIdentityAndTrust = itemsArray.first as? [String : AnyObject] {

                // Get our SecIdentityRef from the PKCS #12 blob

                // TODO: Figure out how to avoid force unwrap here
                // unsafeBitCast is just as bad
                let outIdentity = myIdentityAndTrust[kSecImportItemIdentity as String] as! SecIdentityRef
                status = SecIdentityCopyCertificate(outIdentity, &myReturnedCertificate)

                if status != errSecSuccess {
                    print("Failed to retrieve the certificate associated with the requested identity.")
                } else {
                    // Get the private key associated with our identity
                    status = SecIdentityCopyPrivateKey(outIdentity, &privateKey)

                    if status != errSecSuccess {
                        print("Failed to extract the private key from the keystore.")
                    } else {
                        // Retrieve the digital signature and sign the requestor

                        // Unwrap privateKey from optional SecKeyRef
                        if let privateKey = privateKey {

                            // Get the maximum size of the digital signature
                            var signedBytesSize: size_t = SecKeyGetBlockSize(privateKey)

                            // alloc a buffer to hold the signature
                            // TODO: See if we can use a Swift Array here instead of C types
                            signedBytes = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(signedBytesSize * strideof(UInt8.self))
                            memset(signedBytes, 0x0, signedBytesSize)

                            // We're calling alloc here, so we need to destroy and deinit
                            defer {
                                signedBytes.destroy()
                                signedBytes.dealloc(signedBytesSize * strideof(UInt8.self))
                            }

                            // Sign data
                            if let requestorData = requestorID.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {

                                // Generate a digital signature for our requestor from our cert
                                securityStatus = SecKeyRawSign(privateKey, SecPadding.PKCS1, UnsafePointer(requestorData.bytes), requestorData.length, signedBytes, &signedBytesSize)

                                if securityStatus == errSecSuccess {
                                    let encryptedBytes = NSData(bytes: signedBytes, length: signedBytesSize)
                                    signedRequestorId = encryptedBytes.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
                                } else {
                                    print("Cannot sign the device id info: failed obtaining the signed bytes.")
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    } else {
        print("Cannot sign the device id info: failed importing keystore.")
    }

    return signedRequestorId
}
```

- I put in a few comments to walk through what was going on for my team.  They are not familiar with Swift and even less familiar with low level programming with CoreFoundation.  I struggled to wrap my head on exactly what is going on when I first wrote this code, so please let me know if the comments can be improved for clarity.
- I'm able to use Swift types in place of CoreFoundation types (`CFDictionaryRef`, `CFArrayRef`, etc.), but how do I retrieve a CoreFoundation type from a Swift dictionary without force-unwrapping?  Specifically `myIdentityAndTrust[kSecImportItemIdentity as String] as! SecIdentityRef`.
- I `alloc` a buffer to hold the signed bytes, but I'm sure I can use a Swift array instead thanks to Martin's great answer on a different question of mine about [AES-128 bit encryption](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/139649/73433).
- I'm not too happy with the `if-else` structure of this code.  Is it bad practice to reuse the `OSStatus` variable like this?  What other options are there to structure my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In a `guard` statement with multiple optional bindings, use `let` also for the second
  and subsequent bindings. That is easier to read (and required in Swift 3). Also start
  a new line for each clause in the `guard` statement:

  ```
  guard let certificatePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Certificate", ofType: "p12"),
      let certificateData = NSData(contentsOfFile: certificatePath) else {
      return nil
  }
  ```
- Declare variables at the narrowest scope where they are used, and not at the top
  of the function. This applies e.g. to

  ```
  var signedBytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>
  var privateKey: SecKeyRef?
  var myReturnedCertificate: SecCertificateRef?
  ```
- Early-return in the case of an error to avoid the deep if-nesting.
- The size (and stride) of `UInt8` is 1, there is no need to multiply.
- A conversion to UTF-8 cannot fail, it is safe to force-unwrap

  ```
  let requestorData = requestorID.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
  ```
- As a function argument, `SecPadding.PKCS1` can be shortened to `.PKCS1` because the
  type is inferred from the context.
- Try to avoid very long lines.
- Reusing the `status` variable is acceptable here in my opinion. The only disadvantage
  is that you cannot declare it as a constant. Alternatives would be to use
  separate variables for each call, or to use a local scope for each call:

  ```
  do {
      let status = SecPKCS12Import(certificateData, options, &optItems)
      if status != errSecSuccess { ... }
  }
  ```

  *If* you reuse the `status` variable then there is no need for another
  `securityStatus` variable.

The function then looks like this:

```
func signRequestorId(requestorID: String) -> String? {

    guard let certificatePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Certificate", ofType: "p12"),
        let certificateData = NSData(contentsOfFile: certificatePath) else {
            return nil
    }

    var status: OSStatus

    let certificateKey = "certificateKey"
    let options = [kSecImportExportPassphrase as String : certificateKey]

    var optItems: CFArrayRef?
    status = SecPKCS12Import(certificateData, options, &optItems)
    if status != errSecSuccess {
        print("Cannot sign the device id info: failed importing keystore.")
        return nil
    }
    guard let items = optItems else {
        return nil
    }

    // Cast CFArrayRef to Swift Array
    let itemsArray = items as [AnyObject]
    // Cast CFDictionaryRef as Swift Dictionary
    guard let myIdentityAndTrust = itemsArray.first as? [String : AnyObject] else {
        return nil
    }

    // Get our SecIdentityRef from the PKCS #12 blob
    let outIdentity = myIdentityAndTrust[kSecImportItemIdentity as String] as! SecIdentityRef
    var myReturnedCertificate: SecCertificateRef?
    status = SecIdentityCopyCertificate(outIdentity, &myReturnedCertificate)
    if status != errSecSuccess {
        print("Failed to retrieve the certificate associated with the requested identity.")
        return nil
    }

    // Get the private key associated with our identity
    var optPrivateKey: SecKeyRef?
    status = SecIdentityCopyPrivateKey(outIdentity, &optPrivateKey)
    if status != errSecSuccess {
        print("Failed to extract the private key from the keystore.")
        return nil
    }
    // Unwrap privateKey from optional SecKeyRef
    guard let privateKey = optPrivateKey else {
        return nil
    }

    // Retrieve the digital signature and sign the requestor

    // Get the maximum size of the digital signature
    var signedBytesSize: size_t = SecKeyGetBlockSize(privateKey)
    var signedBytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>

    // alloc a buffer to hold the signature
    signedBytes = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(signedBytesSize)
    memset(signedBytes, 0x0, signedBytesSize)
    // We're calling alloc here, so we need to destroy and deinit
    defer {
        signedBytes.destroy()
        signedBytes.dealloc(signedBytesSize)
    }

    // Sign data
    let requestorData = requestorID.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    // Generate a digital signature for our requestor from our cert
    status = SecKeyRawSign(privateKey, .PKCS1, UnsafePointer(requestorData.bytes),
                                   requestorData.length, signedBytes, &signedBytesSize)
    if status != errSecSuccess {
        print("Cannot sign the device id info: failed obtaining the signed bytes.")
        return nil
    }

    let encryptedBytes = NSData(bytes: signedBytes, length: signedBytesSize)
    let signedRequestorId = encryptedBytes.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])

    return signedRequestorId
}
```

You can use a Swift array instead of allocating a buffer:

```
    var signedBytesSize: size_t = SecKeyGetBlockSize(privateKey)
    var signedBytes = [UInt8](count: signedBytesSize, repeatedValue: 0)

    // Sign data
    let requestorData = requestorID.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    // Generate a digital signature for our requestor from our cert
    status = SecKeyRawSign(privateKey, .PKCS1, UnsafePointer(requestorData.bytes),
                                   requestorData.length, &signedBytes, &signedBytesSize)
```

Unfortunately, I did not find a good alternative to the forced cast in

```
    let outIdentity = myIdentityAndTrust[kSecImportItemIdentity as String] as! SecIdentityRef
```

There seems to be no way to use a conditional cast `as?` with CoreFoundation types.
You can do a forced cast to `SecIdentityRef?` with an optional binding to check if the
value exists at all in the dictionary:

```
    guard let outIdentity = myIdentityAndTrust[kSecImportItemIdentity as String] as! SecIdentityRef?
        else { return nil }
```

I think it is acceptable, because it is *documented* that the value of the
`kSecImportItemIdentity` is a `SecIdentityRef`. If you want to be on the safe side,
verify the identity of the object by checking the Core Foundation "type id":

```
    guard let outIdentityItem = myIdentityAndTrust[kSecImportItemIdentity as String]
        where CFGetTypeID(outIdentityItem) == SecIdentityGetTypeID() else {
            return nil
    }
    let outIdentity = outIdentityItem as! SecIdentityRef
```

Some more suggestions:

- Make `certificatePath` and `certificateKey` parameters of the function.
- Instead of printing error messages (which you do only in *some* error situations)
  and returning `nil`, make the function `throw` a custom defined error.
  The caller can then decide between calling the function in a `do/catch` context,
  or simply with `try?`.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  One small enhancement: I no longer need to declare `signedBytesSize` as a `size_t` since the `count` parameter of the Array initializer takes an Int.  As always, great answer.

Comment: I'm trying to use this code on a Swift command line tool, but the `SecKeyRaw` functions dont seem available, any clue what I can do?

Comment: @KevinR: SecKeyRawSign is not available on macOS, only on iOS. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966829/seckeyrawsign-osx-with-ec-cert.